# Python script not releasing memory in Linux

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a Python script that reads a CSV that contains URLs to PDFs, opens them, does some analytics, and saves that to another CSV. The input CSV is like this:

```
Bid Number,Items
45455454,['https://example.com/file1.pdf']
230000000237,"['https://example.com/file2.pdf', 'https://example.com/file3.pdf']"
```

So, for every bid, I can have multiple files that I need to check. What I did was create a ProccesPoolExecutor with 50 processes, and each process creates N threads (one per URL). URLs per bid are always less than 10.

The Python script I have is the following:

```
import argparse
import ast
import csv
import fitz
import gc
import pandas as pd
import requests
import threading

from documents import best_document, evaluate_document
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed


def parse_url(url):
    """
    Receives a url and returns a dictionary containing the following keys:
        - url: the url of the document
        - number_of_pages: the number of pages in the document
        - number_of_words: the number of words in the document
        - keywords_counter: the number of keywords in the document
        - negative_keywords_counter: the number of negative keywords in the document
    """
    print(f"(INFO) Processing {url} on thread {threading.current_thread().name}")

    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        return None

    word_count, keywords_counter, negative_keywords_counter, page_count = 0, 0, 0, 0
    try:
        pdf = fitz.open(stream=response.content, filetype="pdf")
        word_count, keywords_counter, negative_keywords_counter = evaluate_document(pdf)
        page_count = pdf.page_count
    except:
        return None
    finally:
        if pdf:
            pdf.close()
            del pdf
        if response:
            response.close()
            del response

    return {
        "url": url,
        "number_of_pages": page_count,
        "number_of_words": word_count,
        "keywords_counter": keywords_counter,
        "negative_keywords_counter": negative_keywords_counter,
    }


def process_bid(bid_number, urls):
    print(f"(INFO) Processing bid number {bid_number}...")

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(urls)) as executor:
        bid_results = []
        futures = [executor.submit(parse_url, url) for url in urls]
        bid_results = [
            future.result()
            for future in as_completed(futures)
            if future.result() is not None
        ]

        del futures
        best_result = None
        if len(bid_results) != 0:
            best_result = best_document(bid_results, bid_number)
        del bid_results
        return (bid_number, best_result)


def main(max_processes=50, input_filename="bids_grouped.csv"):
    last_bid_index = 0

    dataframe = pd.read_csv(input_filename, skiprows=range(1, last_bid_index + 1))

    # Prepare a list to store future objects
    futures = []

    iteration_number = 0
    with open("best_documents.csv", "w+", newline="") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(["Bid Number", "Best Document"])

        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_processes) as executor:
            # Submit tasks
            for _, row in dataframe.iterrows():
                bid_number = row["Bid Number"]
                items = ast.literal_eval(row["Items"])

                future = executor.submit(process_bid, bid_number, items)
                futures.append(future)

            # Collect results as they are completed
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                try:
                    bid_number, best_result = future.result()
                    if best_result:
                        writer.writerow([bid_number, best_result["url"]])
                    else:
                        print(f"(INFO) No feasible documents for bid {bid_number}")

                    print(f"(INFO) Finished processing bid number {bid_number}")
                except Exception as exc:
                    print(f"URL processing generated an exception: {exc}")
                finally:
                    iteration_number += 1
                    if iteration_number % 1000 == 0:
                        gc.collect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("parse_bids.py")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-p",
        "--processes",
        help="Number of max processes to spawn. Each bid is going to be assigned to a process",
        type=int,
        default=50,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-i",
        "--input",
        help="Input CSV containing grouped bids",
        default="bids_grouped.csv",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(f"(INFO) Going to use {args.processes} max processes")
    print(f"(INFO) Using input CSV {args.input}")
    main(args.processes, args.input)
```

The issue I'm having is that the CSV contains millions of lines. I developed the script on a M1 Mac (my everyday machine), and memory does not increase linearly with time.
I need to run it in production on a Linux machine, but for some reason, when I run it, the memory keeps increasing linearly with time (and eventually, I run out of memory and the processes/threads start to fail).
Python version is the same (3.10), and library versions are the same:

```
certifi==2023.11.17
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
cryptography==41.0.7
idna==3.6
numpy==1.26.2
pandas==2.1.4
pycparser==2.21
PyMuPDF==1.23.8
PyMuPDFb==1.23.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3.post1
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
tqdm==4.66.1
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==2.1.0
```

I might be leaking memory somewhere, but I guess I should see that on MacOS, too, if that was the case.

Thanks!

Comment: The garbage collector typically makes the memory available for further use by Python, it doesn't usually release it from the process.

Comment: Any way to release it from the process? Why the difference between macos and linux?

Comment: Killing the process is the best way to do it. It may be difficult to return it to the OS, because the garbage won't necessarily be a contiguous block.